# How to change the "Event" portlet in Plone 3

Tags: python, portlet, plone, zope

I am trying to customize the "Event" portlet in Plone 3 that shows the upcoming events. The "view" link in the footer of that portlet goes to the /events URL. But my site is multi-lingual so that URL is not always correct. For example, the correct URL for Dutch events should be /evenementen.

In my setup I use one folder per language. /en holds all English content, /nl holds all Dutch content, etcetera. The plone root has no portlets so I add the "Event" portlet to both the /nl and /en folder separately. I was looking in the ZMI at the events.pt template and it seems that it takes the URL from a property, but where is that property defines and how can I change it? I can't find the portlet configurations in the ZMI. Here is the snippet from plone.app.portlets.portlets/events.pt:

```
<dd class="portletFooter">
    <a href=""
       class="tile"
       tal:attributes="href view/all_events_link"
       i18n:translate="box_upcoming_events">
            Upcoming events&hellip;
    </a>
    <span class="portletBottomLeft"></span>
    <span class="portletBottomRight"></span>
</dd>
```

So, can I somewhere change that all_events_link property in the ZMI? If so, where?

As an alternative I have also tried to add a "Collection" portlet with a collection that lists all events. But the problem is that the collection portlet doesn't want to show the start and end dates for the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events portlet uses a view to provide it with data, and the expression 'view/all_events_link' calls a [method on that view](http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/portlets/events.py#L75) to provide it with a link. You have 2 options to replace that link:

1. Register your own event portlet that subclasses the old one, and replaces the all_events_link method. This in the heavy customization option, and requires Python coding. See [this mail thread](http://n2.nabble.com/Creating-a-new-portlet-Plone-3-tp3332583p3342170.html) on some general pointers on how to achieve this.
2. Replace just the template with a portlet renderer. Martin Aspeli has [documented this method on Plone.org](http://plone.org/documentation/tutorial/customization-for-developers/portlet-renderers); this only requires some ZCML configuration to get working. You can then copy the events.pt template and replace the portlet footer with one that links to the right location.

Comment: Thanks. That looks useful. I will test it after the weekend.

Comment: The second method worked. I couldn't figure out how to change the link for each language so I simply removed the footer from the portlet all together.